# Comparing increasing or decreasing values in percentages

Tags: statistics, soft-question, percentages

By 2001, 22 percent of the population in my town had reached the age of 65 . Now the number of persons over 65 is about 27 percent of the total population and it's expected to be 38 by 2030.

Is it better to state  that the population older than the age of 65 in my town has increased by 5% between 2001 and 2016, or should i say that the population older than the age of 65 has increased by 23% (22%*1.23 =27%)?

Comment: Neither.  We have no idea how much the population of older people has increased or decrease.  In 2001 it was .22M.  Today it is .27N.  Is .27M > .22M?  Probably but we have no idea.  So it is *not* the population that has increased but the *percentage* of population.  I has increased < < blank > > 5%.  That is it was  some percentage, it is now that percentage *plus* 5%.  Or it increased *by* 23% (it is now 123% what the percentage used to be).  I prefer the first.

Comment: In absolute values it has increased over the time, but it's about the change  in %. I think that neither 5% or 23% is a good answer, so i want to know how other people think about this.

Comment: My point is it is the *percentage* change that has been measured.  In *absolute* terms the percentage increased 5% but it didn't increase *by* 5%.  It's ambiguous because "%" could either mean the absolute of the percent value or it could mean a percentage of the percentage.  I think it be clear to say "increased 5 percentage points" or "the rate increased 123 %" or "the rate increased by 23%".